# Cronjobs run differently (correctly) when command typed at console

Tags: python, bash, shell, cron, scrapy

I have encountered a strange problem with crontab: I have correct entries in crontab, have set my path correctly, and yet still when the jobs are run through crontab, they run differently (e.g. log files are not produced, and data is not written to file). However, when I type the **EXACT** commands at the command line, the scripts work as intended.

This is not likely a permissions problem, as I am running the cronjobs as myself.

Here are the relevant details:

#### Crontab entries:

```
0,30 8-18 * * 1-5 python /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/downloaders/make_whoopy.py

0,30 7-18 * * 1-5 /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers/funny_quotes.sh

0,30 7-20 * * 1-5 /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers/even_funnier_quotes.sh
```

#### /var/log/syslog entries (filtered for CRON)

```
Nov  1 09:00:01 BIGBERTHA CRON[8998]: (rascal) CMD (/home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers/funny_quotes.sh)
Nov  1 09:00:01 BIGBERTHA CRON[8999]: (rascal) CMD (/home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers/even_funnier_quotes.sh)
Nov  1 09:00:01 BIGBERTHA CRON[9004]: (rascal) CMD (python /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/downloaders/make_whoopy.py)
Nov  1 09:09:01 BIGBERTHA CRON[9306]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Nov  1 09:09:01 BIGBERTHA CRON[9313]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Nov  1 09:17:01 BIGBERTHA CRON[9495]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

#### Environment (on Server machine running cron jobs)

```
rascal@BIGBERTHA:~/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers$ which python
/usr/bin/python
rascal@BIGBERTHA:~/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers$ which bash
/bin/bash
rascal@BIGBERTHA:~$ which scrapy
/usr/local/bin/scrapy
```

#### funny_quotes.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. /home/rascal/.profile

cd /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers

scrapy crawl funny_quotes
```

#### Running in command prompt ...

```
rascal@BIGBERTHA:~$ /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers/funny_quotes.sh 
2017-11-01 09:57:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapers)
2017-11-01 09:57:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapers.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapers.spiders'], 'BO
T_NAME': 'scrapers'}
2017-11-01 09:57:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
...
```

Why are jobs being run differently through cron?

Comment: Is this a problem about working directory? Do you use relative path or absolute path in your python scripts? I think you can use `find` to find your logs and data.

Comment: have you tried redirecting the error and output logs to some file while executing them in cronjob ?

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S Yes, I tried piping (redirected stdout and err) to log file - file wasn't even created. Tried using `tee` same outcome.

Comment: from which user you are executing manually ? It is root or rascal ?

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S check syslog output, it's user _rascal_

Comment: Last one, Can you check $PATH variable in both places ? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was related to an environment issue. Cron reported to syslog that it had run the job, yet no files/log files were created.

Eventually, the way I solved this was to add a MAILTO=username to my crontab. After I had done this, when the job run and failed, I saw the error message:

> scrapy: command not found

I then resolved this by adding the following statment to my bash script:

> PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 0):

**1)** According to my knowledge, don't we do `bash funny_quotes.sh` instead of just   `funny_quotes.sh`

**2)** Change your cron commands from

```
python /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/downloaders/make_whoopy.py
```

to

```
cd /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/downloaders/ && python make_whoopy.py
```

and same this one

```
/home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers/funny_quotes.sh
```

to

```
cd /home/rascal/work/skunkworks/scripts/python/scrapers/ && bash funny_quotes.sh
```

**3)** Check your cron logs

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I am sure you are getting error something like `scrapy - command not found` or something similar.

To fix it, do this

Enter and copy the output of `echo $PATH` from shell.

And then open `crontab -e`

At the very top of file, write `PATH=YOUR_COPIED_CONTENTS`

And that should work.

Comment: the commands you suggested, were what I originally had in my crontab. I got rid of the chained commands (and piping output to a logfile using pipes/redirection/tee etc). The problems I had existed back then, I thought (incorrectly), that simplifying the commands (to single commands) would resolve the issue.  In short, I already tried what you suggested - I had the same problems I have reported in this question. Also, I have the syslog entry - cron is definitely running (no reported errors), and also, you can see that scrapy etc, are in the path of user _rascal_.

Comment: what would be the point of that?. I am already sourcing my **entire** environment in the shell scripts that are being run.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Hey, I still believe try my suggestion in point3 ... it will take you just 5 minutes ... maybe it can save you lots of debugging hours :P

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom log for your cron.

```
0,30 8-18 * * 1-5 python /home/.../make_whoopy.py /home/make_whoopy.py.log 2>&1
```

This will send stderr and stdout to make_whoopy.py.log

If you want to see the output in screen (dirty solution)

```
0,30 8-18 * * 1-5 python /home/.../make_whoopy.py > /dev/pts/1
```

Of course this will work when you are logged and have to change /dev/pts/1 accordingly to your tty

Another alternative is send to mail

```
0,30 8-18 * * 1-5 python /home/.../make_whoopy.py > /dev/null 2>&1 | mail -s "cron output" you@example.org
```

And the cherry of the cake is send the output to syslog

```
0,30 8-18 * * 1-5 python /home/.../make_whoopy.py | /usr/bin/logger -t make_whoopy
```

The **-t make_whoopy** will create a tag named make_whoopy on syslog.